# Heroku Application deployment Error when Viewing Dash App in broswer

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, plotly-dash

I am attempting to deploy my dash app built using Python on heroku. The manual deploy by connecting to my [github repo](https://github.com/Gwtham11/dashcsv) branch works fine and says it deployed successfully, but when I visit the page I get the error message:

- "Application error. An error occurred in the application and your
  page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check
  your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku **CLI** with
  the command 'heroku logs --tail'"

My dashboard runs fine when deploying locally.
App log : [App log link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rH8_liBTZ6WEV2taDPQXTByA5zn2ub4t/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is the log of you app?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for responding!!

Comment: I am sorry i could.nt get what you are saying ?

Comment: Did you mean the activity log?

Comment: Yes. Every app must have a minimal log in which you can see what is happening. Heroku has an option to watch your logs https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDwHY.png

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rH8_liBTZ6WEV2taDPQXTByA5zn2ub4t/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JRichardsz    You can find the log in the link

Comment: As you can see, your app is crashed. Restart the app to get more log.  Maybe some clasic error is happening like: database, configuration, python version, etc